# Manipulate a 2d array from QtScript

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

I would like a way to be able to access an array of integers that is created somewhere in my main app from a QtScript, and after doing whatever manipulations that the script might perform return it back again.

What I am able to work until now is single values (e.g. an integer or boolean) and I have not seen an example on what I am describing.

Is there a way of doing that, or I will have to read the data one by one?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the array in a QOBJECT?

Comment: hi @danielfranca, no I am afraid I don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try encapusulating your 2d array in a QObject class, as indicated here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html
and add some methods to manipuate it.

Something like that (didn't test the code, so can contain some errors and is pretty raw)

```
class MyArray: public QObject {
    int** m_array;
    public:
    Q_OBJECT
    MyArray(signed int x, signed int y) {
        m_array = new MyArray[x][y];
    }
    ~MyArray() { delete m_array; }

    Q_INVOKABLE int at(signed int x, signed int y) {
        if (m_array) return m_array[x][y];
    }
    ...
}
```

Than assign it to a QtScript property:

```
MyArray *array2d = new MyArray(10, 5);
QScriptValue arrayValue = engine.newQObject(array2d);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("array2d", arrayValue);
```

Comment: I will test your solution, it seems like a nice idea. What I ended up doing while waiting for your answer is creating two functions `int MainWindow::getValueAt(int x, int y)` and `void setValueAt(int x, int y, int Val)` And added them as public slots to my main class in order to access them from a script.